# How to check if HTML-file is doing external call?

Tags: javascript, call

I let users upload HTML-files (and assets like images and Javascript) to our platform. All HTML-code is allowed, although it should NOT do a call to an external file (so which is not uploaded).

How can we solve this? I'm thinking in the direction of Javascript, but totally not sure where to start.

Sorry it's such an open question, but I hope someone can help me in the right direction.

Comment: Once you start allowing JavaScript this becomes massively difficult to do.

Comment: No matter how you try to protect yourself, there will always be work arounds.

Comment: I can check all calls while running the HTML-code and using something like Firebug or Tamper data. Maybe there's some workaround to check all those calls with some scripting as well.